# Ambiguous results from Espresso on a fairly basic test

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

We have a page that in a sense acts like email.  So we have a Recyclerview with a bunch of TextViews, one of them being a large TextView containing all the email content.

So we are just trying to test that the entire text of the email is loaded and displayed (we append a special string at the end and we are going to test that is shows up).

```
Espresso.onView( Matchers.allOf(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed(), ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.email_content)) )
            .perform(ViewActions.scrollTo(), ViewActions.swipeUp());
```

When this is ran we get this error:

```
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'click (after 3 attempts)' on view 'unknown'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendDown(MotionEvents.java:111)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Swipe.sendLinearSwipe(Swipe.java:88)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Swipe.access$100(Swipe.java:31)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Swipe$1.sendSwipe(Swipe.java:38)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralSwipeAction.perform(GeneralSwipeAction.java:70)
```

So when we change it to this:

```
    Espresso.onView( Matchers.allOf(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed(), ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.email_content)) )
            .perform(ViewActions.swipeUp());
```

We get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints: 
at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.
Target view: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131558822, res-name=email_content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1048, height=1513896, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=16.0, y=175.0, text=
```

Why in the 1st case it says it couldn't scroll the view and in the 2nd case it says it isn't fully visible enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewActions.scrollTo()` can not be used with `RecyclerView` because scrollTo requires to work only with objects that inherited from ScrollView. To scroll to necessary item in `RecyclerView` you should write your own ViewAction. You can take a look how to make this [here](http://droidtestlab.com/additions.html) see method `scrollToPosition`

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

When I use swipeDown() it was ok, but swipeUp() produced the exact same error:

```
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'click (after 3 attempts)' on view 'unknown'.
```

I was trying to simulate/test swipe up on a recycler view in a fragment. It would fetch new data from the server as it passes 60% of the number of items in recycler view.

Android Studio 2.3.1

Windows 7

Genymotion Samsung S6

My temporary solution to simulate the behavior is done below. Hope this helps someone with the exact same behaviour and error.

MyFragment.java

```
        ...
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            ...
            else if(mainActivity.isAutomatedTesting && dy < 0) //check for scroll up. isAutomatedTesting is set to true in MyTest.java
            {
                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                lastVisibleItemPos = mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                if (loading)
                {
                    if ( (lastVisibleItemPos / totalItemCount) >= listTolerance)
                    {                            
                        //fetch new data
                    }
                }
            }
            ...
```

MyTest.java

```
        //wait for first lot of data to finish loading
        try {
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int count = 1;
        int maxCount = 4;
        while(count < maxCount) {

            onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
                    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(count * 9));
            onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
                    .perform(swipeDown());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(15000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            count++;
        }
```